# Standard output strange behavior

Tags: c++, c++11, eclipse-cdt

I have an issue using Eclipse cdt and I am facing a strange behavior:

```
cout << "Hello world" << endl;
aFunction();
// The output here is Hello world
// END
```

When I take off the `endl` the output is nothing

```
cout << "Hello world";
aFunction();
// No output
// END
```

and when I put the `endl` later it works fine :

```
cout << "Hello world";
aFunction();
cout << endl;
// output is Hello world
// END
```

Now, I can't provide the function code, because it will take me a thousand of lines.

However, I tried this with a function that does nothing `void toto(){}` and there was not this strange thing .

```
cout << "Hello world";
toto();
// Gives me Hello world
// END
```

What I want to know is what can cause this ??

**EDIT :** 
The tests with foo are tested alone (no other instructions), 
In the other tests, I initialize a structure that I give as a parameter to `aFunction`.  The function uses some metaprogramming and there is a lot of code i need to show so you understand it.

Comment: What happens after the call to `toto`? Can you please edit your question to include complete programs, [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Editted

Comment: As the stream buffers are flushed when the program exits, and the program exits cleanly after the `aFunction` call is done, that means the output should have been shown. Are you sure the `aFunction` function finishes properly? It doesn't crash or otherwise causes the program to exit abnormally?

Comment: Well when I add `cout << " something " << endl;` after it, I get Hello world somehting, it means that it works fine no ?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg it was actually the struct I initialized before... its destructor crashes

Answer (score 4):

When writing to streams, they are normally *buffered*, meaning the output is stored in an internal buffer (chunk of memory). When that buffer is full, or when the stream is explicitly told to, then the buffer is flushed and the output is actually written to the file or device.

The [`std::endl`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl) [I/O manipulator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip) not only adds a newline, it also flushes the buffers in the stream, causing the buffered output to be actually be written.

Comment: So why I don't need it with `toto` function ?

Comment: @OthmanBenchekroun Without more context it's hard to know. For example, what happens *after* the function calls? Does the program doing the `aFunction` call continue and the program doing the `toto` call exit? The stream buffers are flushed when they are destructed, which for the `std::cout` buffer is when the program exits.

Answer (score 1):

`std::endl` adds a new line *and* flushes the stream you give it to.

You can just flush a stream with `std::flush`.

Comment: @OthmanBenchekroun stream buffering is pretty non-deterministic, so replacing a function with another may well change its behaviour. Your runtime environment might not automatically flush the buffer on process exit. The bottom line is : if you want buffered output to be visible immediately, use `std::flush` or `std::endl`.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling

```
std::ostream::flush()
```

to flush the stream buffer. Thats job is done by `endl` and when you take it off, the message keeps waiting ready in the buffer, to be flushed when the buffer is full or when a new line comes.

So you can flush it yourself if you want to.

Comment: Hum... but the link there says the program exited. Not the example here. Do your program terminate and still not print the string?

Comment: Well, the way you asked seems impossible to solve. Does function `aFunc()` clears the `I/O` buffer, for instance? What else? Should I keep guessing? Sorry, pal.

Comment: Well that is exactly my question :  "What I want to know is what can cause this ?? "